# Exporting Listview in Visual Studio Into Microsoft Excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, export-to-excel

I am new in creating Report System using Visual Stuido 2010 C#. I already have a listview in my forms where it has all the information needed for the report. I am planning to integrate it with Microsoft Excel. What I want is that the user is capable of exporting the reports in the listview into Microsoft Excel. Is there anything I can read or research on how to do this? Or is it even possible? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:
  http://www.dotnetlogix.com/article/aspnet/56/How-to-export-listview-in-excel-in-asp.net.html
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/ExportASPNetDataGridToExcel11222005041447AM/ExportASPNetDataGridToExcel.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the data source and write values into `CSV` (comma separated) file. I think this will be the simplest way. (Must read article : [Why are the Microsoft Office file formats so complicated? (And some workarounds)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html) by Joel Spolsky).